# Error in Eclipse Papyrus

Tags: eclipse, papyrus

I installed Papyrus on Eclipse Oxygen, opened a new model, opened a new use-case diagram, created a new use-case and added some documentation. When I tried to edit the documentation and save it, I got the following error:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>   file:///home/erelsgl/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.richtext_1.2.0.201703081533/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/richtext/resources/template.html:54:43: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData')

Is this a bug in Papyrus? In Eclipse? In another component?

Is there a quick solution that will enable me to continue working?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug. 'undefined' is not an object. It seems that your newly created documentation was not available within the Papyrus model, so it said undefined. I did not find a matching bug within Bugzilla.

Workaround: Create the model elements without editing the documentation. Save it. Close it, reopen it, refresh it (F5). Try do edit the documentation, save it.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug.

Best guess is to disable RichText in preferences: 
Window > Preferences > Papyrus > Rich Text

If you really need RichText in your use case, you can open a [bug in Papyrus](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Papyrus) prefixing your title by [RichText] but without more information, it's quite impossible to say if it's coming from [Nebula widget](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/richtext/richtext.php) or from its integration in [Papyrus](https://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/)